# Parallel starting of services at the time of boot

Tags: boot, scripts, init.d, init

I am having a bit slow boot because of many services.
Services listed below (Output for `sudo ls -l /etc/rc$(sudo runlevel| awk '{print $2}').d`):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar 21  2020 K01whoopsie -> ../init.d/whoopsie
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 21  2020 S01acpid -> ../init.d/acpid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Mar 21  2020 S01anacron -> ../init.d/anacron
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 21  2020 S01apport -> ../init.d/apport
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Mar 21  2020 S01avahi-daemon -> ../init.d/avahi-daemon
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Mar 21  2020 S01bluetooth -> ../init.d/bluetooth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Mar 21  2020 S01console-setup.sh -> ../init.d/console-setup.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 21  2020 S01cron -> ../init.d/cron
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 21  2020 S01cups -> ../init.d/cups
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Mar 21  2020 S01cups-browsed -> ../init.d/cups-browsed
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 21  2020 S01dbus -> ../init.d/dbus
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Dec 31 23:43 S01docker -> ../init.d/docker
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 21  2020 S01gdm3 -> ../init.d/gdm3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 21  2020 S01grub-common -> ../init.d/grub-common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 21  2020 S01irqbalance -> ../init.d/irqbalance
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 21  2020 S01kerneloops -> ../init.d/kerneloops
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec  9 21:21 S01nmbd -> ../init.d/nmbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Dec 12 22:31 S01openvpn -> ../init.d/openvpn
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar 21  2020 S01plymouth -> ../init.d/plymouth
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 May  6 20:56 S01postfix -> ../init.d/postfix
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 21  2020 S01rsync -> ../init.d/rsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Mar 21  2020 S01rsyslog -> ../init.d/rsyslog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Dec  9 21:21 S01samba-ad-dc -> ../init.d/samba-ad-dc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 21  2020 S01saned -> ../init.d/saned
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May  6 20:56 S01smartmontools -> ../init.d/smartmontools
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Dec  9 21:21 S01smbd -> ../init.d/smbd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Mar 21  2020 S01speech-dispatcher -> ../init.d/speech-dispatcher
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Mar 21  2020 S01spice-vdagent -> ../init.d/spice-vdagent
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec  9 21:15 S01ssh -> ../init.d/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Dec 12 23:22 S01stunnel4 -> ../init.d/stunnel4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 21  2020 S01unattended-upgrades -> ../init.d/unattended-upgrades
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 21  2020 S01uuidd -> ../init.d/uuidd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Dec 12 23:22 S01windscribe-cli -> ../init.d/windscribe-cli
```

I want to make these services start in parallel during the boot and I think this code will do the job for the same level services to be executed parallelly:

```
for i in /etc/rc$runlevel.d/S*
do
 case "$runlevel" in
  0|6) startup $i stop ;;
  *) startup $i start ;;
 esac
done
```

But the problem is I don't know where should I put this code. I **can't even find /etc/init.d/rc script**

Comment: Does `systemd` use `init` scripts? I don't think so...

Comment: I referred this [blog](https://www.linux.com/news/boot-faster-parallel-starting-services/)

Comment: I admit that I am not expert on this topic (and I hope somebody with better knowledge will comment or answer your question); however, are you aware that your reference is more than 15 years old?

Comment: Yes, i am. That's why i am finding an answer for newer kernel. Maybe by modifying systemd or something to work, idk